# css - fit all content inside a div, center background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

[image: Screenshot illustrating the issue]

As shown in the screenshot, there are contents inside a `div` element which has a background image. This `div` container is set to have `height: 40%` of its parent, I believe it is `<ion-content>` in this case. Now, the image and the text underneath are cropped. I want to make them fit inside the `div` container. The background image is also not centered in the `div`.

1. How can I style it such that all the contents can be displayed?
2. How can I center my background image both vertically and horizontally?

It somehow works if I make the browser viewport narrower as shown below. However, I would like to have **everything displayed** and **the background image centered both vertically and horizontally** regardless the width of the viewport.

[image: Screenshot illustrating the expected result]

---

### HTML

```
<div style="height: 40%; overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="user-profile">
        <div class="user-profile-background"></div>
        <div class="user-profile-content">
            <div class="row" style="height: 100%;">
                <div class="col col-center">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-33 col-offset-33">
                            <div style="height: 0; border-radius: 50%; background-image: url('img/ionic.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center center; padding-top: 100%;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col" style="text-align: center; color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 1);">
                            <h3 style="color: white;">Seraph Cheng</h3>
                            <p><strong>Male, 28</strong></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.user-profile {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.user-profile .user-profile-background {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('../img/basketball.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}

.user-profile .user-profile-content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

---

### Edit

Added a [CodePen link](http://codepen.io/aldour/pen/mPVdLz) to illustrate my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### HTML

```
<div class="root">
  <div class="subroot">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="square bg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="passage">
      <p>Hello world!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.root {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  background-image: url('http://baconmockup.com/600/400');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.subroot {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}

.square {
  border: 2px dotted red;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.bg {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200x300');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.passage {
  border: 2px dotted green;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: scroll;
  color: white;
}
```

Problem solved.

[image: Problem solved]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `background-size: cover` css rule. You can test the difference between cover and contain here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=contain

It's fully compatibility with latest browsers: http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts

Try this:

```
.user-profile .user-profile-background {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('../img/basketball.jpg');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set an explicit `height` for the `background image` for example `height = 350px` and set `center center` as the position property where you have specified the background image. This way the height will remain fixed but as the view port is reduced, the background image will start cropping from left and right sides i.e it would remain in the center.
Then on smaller view port, you can reduce the `height` to say `250px`.